# is there a way to link fragment sequences to their respective weight?

Tags: python

i've made a script that will calculate wheter or not a set of protein fragments can form a specific sequence based on their weight, which has given me the folowing output:

```
combinations =
[(484.5, 1036.3, 2267.6), 
(397.5, 2267.6, 475.6, 647.7), 
(484.5, 1036.3, 811.9, 1455.7),  
(397.5, 475.6, 811.9, 647.7, 1455.7)]
```

with each element being a set of fragments that have the same weight as the protein i'm looking for.
now i know which fragments have which weight and made that into a dictionary:

```
{3125.4: 'SKEPFKTRIDKKPCDHNTEPYMSGGNY',
 1963.4: 'KMITKARPGCMHQMGEY',
 397.5: 'AINV',
 484.5: 'QIQD',
 1036.3: 'YAINVMQCL',
 2267.6: 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV',
 475.6: 'MQCL',
 1724.0: 'HMTPCYELHGLRWV',
 2000.2: 'DHTAQPCRSWPMDYPLT',
 811.9: 'IEEATHM',
 1397.7: 'MVGKMDMLEQYA',
 681.8: 'GWPDII',
 647.7: 'QIQDY',
 2174.4: 'TPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYA',
 1794.0: 'HGLRWVQIQDYAINV',
 1040.3: 'KKKNARKW',
 1455.7: 'TPCYELHGLRWV'}
```

is there any way to use the dictionary to give me an output like this:

```
[('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL'),
 ('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQDY', 'AINV', 'MQCL'),
 ('IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL'),
 ('IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQDY', 'AINV', 'MQCL')]
```

for the elements in combinations?

Comment: Please include your python code.

Comment: Are you looking to make digestion product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combinations =[(484.5, 1036.3, 2267.6), 
(397.5, 2267.6, 475.6, 647.7), 
(484.5, 1036.3, 811.9, 1455.7),  
(397.5, 475.6, 811.9, 647.7, 1455.7)]

m = {3125.4: 'SKEPFKTRIDKKPCDHNTEPYMSGGNY',
 1963.4: 'KMITKARPGCMHQMGEY',
 397.5: 'AINV',
 484.5: 'QIQD',
 1036.3: 'YAINVMQCL',
 2267.6: 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV',
 475.6: 'MQCL',
 1724.0: 'HMTPCYELHGLRWV',
 2000.2: 'DHTAQPCRSWPMDYPLT',
 811.9: 'IEEATHM',
 1397.7: 'MVGKMDMLEQYA',
 681.8: 'GWPDII',
 647.7: 'QIQDY',
 2174.4: 'TPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYA',
 1794.0: 'HGLRWVQIQDYAINV',
 1040.3: 'KKKNARKW',
 1455.7: 'TPCYELHGLRWV'}

[tuple(m[i] for i in c) for c in combinations]
```

Output

```
[('QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV'),
 ('AINV', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'QIQDY'),
 ('QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV'),
 ('AINV', 'MQCL', 'IEEATHM', 'QIQDY', 'TPCYELHGLRWV')]
```